# Minecraft Login system

Tags: java, minecraft

Nevermind, code is fixed.........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you've made is incomplete as @user681574 stated, so unfortunately your question will be answered in a vague way. 
It seems like you have to make objects appear when the player has successfully logged in as it is the easiest way possible. Another way is to make the players not able to register clicks/keys until they have logged in. In this way, the player will be "frozen" and forced to login. Also be sure to add a timeout to avoid having your server full of AFK players or bot-attacks.

Good luck with your plugin!

Comment: I've updated the code here - https://www.hastebin.com/nomutaxega.cs
And I still need help

Answer (score 0):

This code appears to be incomplete, and the Login.java is a duplicate of Register.java, so the question isn't really possible to answer.

However, generically the answer is that you must pass your UI object into the class that evaluates whether a person is logged in initially.  If they are not logged in, access the hotbar object from the UI object and use the methods available to that hotbar object stop it from registering clicks.